# How to ignore 'redeclarations' of a type?

Tags: php, function, class, reference, declaration

I'm building a 'core' for php. That 'core' is loaded before to load an application, for example Wordpress. Now, for example the 'phpmailerException' class is a part of Wordpress, but it is a part of the 'core' too. How can I ignore the fatal error: 'cannot redeclare...'. ¿There is way using php.ini or a special function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a check with [class_exists](https://www.php.net/class_exists) , and then declare your classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by `core`.

I assume that's a php file your created.

If you load (by include/require) it at the beginning, then you can't prevent the `cannot redeclare` error. There is no way to skip such error by settings.

If the `core` is something like a plugin, then you could use `class_exists`, `function_exists` to check whether a class or a function is already declared.

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth checking if WordPress is using `include_once/require_once` instead of `include/require`. If WordPress is using `include_once/require_once` you have to make sure you are using `include_once/require_once` as well. That way, you can be sure your classes will be included *once*